# Javascript Custom Base32

Tags: javascript, base32

I am trying to implement base32 with a custom charset, basically [A-Z0-5]. 
Unfortunately I am failing to build the lookup table for that.

Does anyone have any pointers on how I can go about building the whole encoding and decoding scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at existing base32 implementations ( https://github.com/agnoster/base32-js ), it's usually not longer than a few 100 lines.